# How to stack Bootstrap row inside of another row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap page on which I'm trying to stack different boxes.

[Imgur - Image of boxes (sorry, not enough rep to upload images directly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9WAP.png)

The green boxes are the ones currently in position, and the red ones are the ones I am having issues with. I'm using the following code (simplified) to get the green boxes:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="height:100px; background-color:green;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3" style="height:100px; background-color:green;">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6" style="height:200px; background-color:green;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm basically trying to create another two `<div class="col-xs-3" style="height:100px; background-color:green;">` that will go underneath the current two, while also keeping the large box to the right.

I thought it would be an easy fix with a new row, or using `float:left / right`, but none of that seems to be working out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to make two 50% width columns and then divide the column on the right into two rows with two more columns in each:

```css
.green-lrg {
  background-color:green;
  height:215px;
}
.green-sml {
  background-color:green;
  height:100px;
}
.red-sml {
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
}
.col-xs-6 .row {
  padding-top:15px;
}
  .col-xs-6 .row:first-child {
    padding-top:0;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- LEFT COLUMN -->
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="green-lrg"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="green-sml"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="green-sml"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="red-sml"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="red-sml"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example. 
**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 box box-big">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 box box-small">

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 box box-small">

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 box box-small">

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 box box-small">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and **CSS**:

```
.box {
  background-color:green;  
  border:5px solid white;
}

.box-big {
  height:200px;
}

.box-small {
  height:100px;
}
```